Error 'shared_logicflows' When Exporting Power App
When exporting a power app that we have at work I get this error:
"The caller object id is 'GUID1'. Connection 'GUID2' to 'shared_logicflows' cannot be used to activate this flow, either because this is not a valid connection or because it is not a connection you have access permission for. Either replace the connection with a valid connection you can access or have the connection owner activate the flow, so the connection is shared with you in the context of this flow."
I was given all the appropriate permissions to the flows associated to this app, is it possible that they forgot to give me permissions to an underlying Flow?
